# Checking response status of web pages and getting intermittent timing out replies

Tags: c#, networking, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am creating a windows service that checks the status of various services that I have. The problem is that 9 times out of 10, the response "times out". There was a few times that google.ca timed out.

Here is my code

```
try
{
    var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "password", "domain");
    // Associate the 'NetworkCredential' object with the 'WebRequest' object.
    myRequest.Credentials = networkCredential;
    myRequest.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;
    myRequest.KeepAlive = true;
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        bool isJson = Regex.IsMatch(url, "JSON", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (isJson)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            if (sr.ReadToEnd().Contains("error"))
            {
                errorMessages = (string.Format("{0} unavailable: {1}", url, "The document contains the word error"));
                return false;
            }

        }

        return true;

    }
    else
    {
        errorMessages = (string.Format("{0} Returned, but with status: {1}", url, response.StatusDescription));
        return false;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //  not available at all, for some reason
    errorMessages = (string.Format("{0} unavailable: {1}", url, ex.Message));
    return false;
}
```

**What I think the issue is**

If I disable the cache in Chrome, when I visit some of the pages, some of the time, chrome thinks the page is still loading, even though the image or page is fully loaded.

Is there anyway I can adjust my code to accommodate this?

EDIT: ADDED

```
myRequest.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;
myRequest.KeepAlive = true;
```

And now it just hangs indefinitely.

EDIT:

Is there a way to see if the page partially loads? I could remove the infinite timeout, and read it as a streamreader object to see if it at least loads partially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also add in the UserAgent string as some web servers will block repeated requests from the same IP address without it.

You might also want to add in a cookie container and retain it between requests.

However, be polite - don't forget you're adding to a web servers load. If it's your own website then fine - but if it's someone elses - you should use a UserAgent that identifies you, follow their robot.txt file directives and use a suitable time between requests.

Comment: I added the useragent string, and have the requests timed 15 minutes apart. I'll let it run and see what happens.

Comment: Adding the useragent string seems to have resolved my issue, thank you!